# What's wrong with this function? - R

Tags: r

The function follows:

```
qual <- function(x, y, z)
{if ((abs(x - y) <= .15)&(abs(x - z) <= .15)&(abs(y - z) <= .15)){print("grade A")} 
else if((abs(x - y) <= .15)|(abs(x - z) <= .15)){print("grade B")} 
else if((abs(x - y) <= .2)|(abs(x - z) <= .2)){print("grade C")} 
else if((abs(x - y) <= .25)|(abs(x - z) <= .25)){print("grade D")} 
else {print("check manually")}}
```

It seems that, e.g., the output of `qual(1.19, 1.04, 1.06)` and `qual(1.10, .95, .97)`should be "grade A". However, the output is "grade A" and "grade B", respectively.

Why is this?

Comment: I think you are running into floating point precision errors, look at `abs(1.10 - 0.95) <= 0.15`.

Comment: @Marius I'm pretty sure that's it, that difference should be `0.15000000000000013` or so.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are hitting some floating point precision problems. See [Why are these numbers not equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal/) for a full explanation.

To fix this, you can use a short function that takes into account minor precision errors when comparing:

```
less_equal_safe <- function(x, y) {
    (x < y) | dplyr::near(x, y)
}

qual <- function(x, y, z) {
    if (less_equal_safe(abs(x - y), .15) & (abs(x - z) <= .15) &(abs(y - z) <= .15)) {
        print("grade A")
    } else if ((abs(x - y) <= .15) | (abs(x - z) <= .15)) {
        print("grade B")
    } else if ((abs(x - y) <= .2) | (abs(x - z) <= .2)) {
        print("grade C")
    } 
    else if ((abs(x - y) <= .25) | (abs(x - z) <= .25)) {
        print("grade D")
    } else {
        print("check manually")
    }
}
```

(note that you need the `dplyr` package to be installed to use `dplyr::near`)

I've only replaced the first comparison, which is the one that was causing the issue, but ideally you should replace *all* comparisons in your function with the float-safe function.